# Accessing Web application on a NLB Environment having Session values

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, event-receivers

I am having a multi server production environment with `2 WFEs ,2 Index Servers, 2 SQL Server` boxes. I have deployed my wsp on these 2 WFEs. The issue I am facing is when the NLB switches from one IP address to another my web application is crashing. I have used session variables in my custom solution. So  how to enable my web site working with these kind of environment. How can I enable session state in this NLB environment.Here,in my customer environment NLB is being configured as combination of software and hardware.

Comment: Did you enable the SessionState Service?

Comment: russellg, Yes,I already enabled SessionState Service.But that did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling session affinity / sticky sessions in your NLB. You don't mention any details here. Are you on 2013?

Comment: Peter, Yes , am using SP 2013 environment.Will try enabling affinity.